# How to use vtkCylinderSource to make cylinder be vertical aligned

Tags: vtk

I use python to create cylinder in vtk format

```
cylinder = vtk.vtkCylinderSource()
cylinder.SetRadius(4)
cylinder.SetHeight(8)
cylinder.SetCenter(0,0,0)
cylinder.SetResolution(12)
cylinder.Update()
writer = vtk.vtkPolyDataWriter()
writer.SetInputData(cylinder.GetOutput())
writer.SetFileName('cylinder.vtk')
writer.Update()
sphereMesh = pv.read('cylinder.vtk')
plotter.add_mesh(sphereMesh, color='#9C7FF1', show_edges=show_ed)
plotter.add_axes()
```

This a result of visualization:

[image]

How can I change it to be symetric around z not y

Answer (score 1):

```py
import vtk

cylinder = vtk.vtkCylinderSource()
cylinder.SetRadius(4)
cylinder.SetHeight(8)
cylinder.SetCenter(0,0,0)
cylinder.SetResolution(12)
cylinder.Update()
writer = vtk.vtkPolyDataWriter()
writer.SetInputData(cylinder.GetOutput())
writer.SetFileName('cylinder.vtk')
writer.Update()

# with pyvista:
import pyvista as pv
plotter = pv.Plotter()
sphereMesh = pv.read('cylinder.vtk')
sphereMesh.rotate_x(90)
plotter.add_mesh(sphereMesh, color='#9C7FF1', show_edges=1)
plotter.add_axes()
plotter.show()

# with vedo:
import vedo
# vedo.Cylinder().write('cylinder.vtk')
vedo.load('cylinder.vtk').rotateX(90).c('#9C7FF1').lw(1).show(axes=1)
```

[image]